# Load image from current theme

Tags: image, drupal

i am doing a module... and i want to show an html that contents an image(that is on de images folder of my current theme).

```
function hello_menu() {
  $items['say/hello'] = array(
  'title' => 'hello',
  'page callback' => 'hello',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function hello() {
  return '<p class="saludo"><em>Hello World</em><img src="images/myimage.png"/></p>';
}
```

But the problem is that i can not see the image. I think it must be beacuse of some path problem.

What function i must use, and how if i can generate this simple html?

Best regards

Comment: See the link in the above comment, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

In D6/7/8, the global variable $theme_path ought to do the trick.

See API docs: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals/6